# 95m Difference between R .laz file spTransform() and the Result from epsg.io - why?

Tags: coordinate-system

In comparing R's result using spTransform() to reproject an .laz file, I find that its result in one case is 95m off that given by epsg.io for the same reprojection.

I have found that results from R and LAStools (run via QGIS) with each other and that results from epsg.io and from https://mygeodata.cloud/cs2cs/ agree with each other, so something is systematically amiss with what is happening on my PC vs what is happening with the online transformations.

- Can you help me understand why this is happening?  Do I misunderstand transformation as being the same thing as reprojection?

Full example below, if helpful:

```
> # Test to compare R's projection transform with that of epsg.io
> 
> #rm(list = ls()); gc()
> 
> library(lidR) # also loads raster and sp packages
> library(sf)
> 
> #setwd("C:/MappingProjects/Project_20210209_CeriseParkMontrose/Lidar/")
> # download .laz file from TNM USGS Download, using "-107.882239°, 38.460569°"
> # setwd() here
> las.in1 <- readLAS("USGS_LPC_CO_WestCentral_2019_A19_w1024n1778.laz")
> wkt(las.in1)
[1] "COMPD_CS[\"NAD83(2011) / Conus Albers + NAVD88 height - Geoid12B (m)\",PROJCS[\"NAD83(2011) / Conus Albers\",GEOGCS[\"NAD83(2011)\",DATUM[\"NAD83 (National Spatial Reference System 2011)\",SPHEROID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7019\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"1116\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6318\"]],PROJECTION[\"Albers_Conic_Equal_Area\"],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_1\",29.5],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_2\",45.5],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_center\",23],PARAMETER[\"longitude_of_center\",-96],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",0],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0],UNIT[\"meter\",1,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]],AXIS[\"X\",EAST],AXIS[\"Y\",NORTH],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6350\"]],VERT_CS[\"NAVD88 height - Geoid12B (m)\",VERT_DATUM[\"North American Vertical Datum 1988\",2005,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"5103\"]],UNIT[\"meter\",1,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]],AXIS[\"Up\",UP],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"5703\"]]]"
> crs(las.in)
CRS arguments:
 +proj=aea +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +vunits=m +no_defs 
> 
> # attempt to transform using OGSWKT
> # las.out <- spTransform(las.in1, CRS('PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 13N",GEOGCS["WGS 84",
> # DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
> # AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
> # UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
> # PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
> # PARAMETER["central_meridian",-105],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
> # PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,
> # AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
> # AUTHORITY["EPSG","32613"]]'))
> 
> # attempt to transform using EPSG code (same result as with OGSWKT above):
> las.out <- spTransform(las.in1, CRS("+init=epsg:32613"))
> 
> crs(las.out)
CRS arguments:
 +proj=utm +zone=13 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
> las.in1@bbox
       min      max
x -1024000 -1023000
y  1778000  1779000
> las.out@bbox
        min       max
x  248879.7  249980.1
y 4260326.2 4261404.4
> 
> # per epsg.io (5070, 5071, 5072, 6350)
> # https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=6350&t_srs=32613&x=-1024000.0000000&y=1778000.0000000
> minX = 248974.68   # 5069 = 248941.74
> minY = 4260326.01   # 5069 = 4260385.05
> # same output as with my GEoCloud: https://mygeodata.cloud/cs2cs/
> 
> # Error:
> X.err <- las.out@bbox[1, 1] - minX
> X.err
[1] -95.02
> # Y Error
> Y.err <- las.out@bbox[2, 1] - minY
> Y.err
[1] 0.14
> sqrt((X.err)^2 + (Y.err)^2)
[1] 95.0201
> 
> # compare to reprojection in LAStools - agrees with R, not with epsg.io
> las.lastools <- readLAS("n1024_1778_reproject.laz")
> las.lastools@bbox
        min       max
x  248879.7  249980.1
y 4260326.2 4261404.4
```

Comment: Another data point: the DEM created in OCAD using the R-based reprojection agrees with with the OSM base map.

Comment: Please edit your question and tidy your source code. It is unreadable as is. Remove code and comments not related to your question. Remove `>` everywhere. Split the code in chunks of related content. And use plain text to explain what you did outside of R. Add proper tags to your question. And add information about `lidR`, `sp`, `sf` and `rgdal` versions as well as the output of `rgdal::rgdal_extSoftVersion()`.

Comment: @JRR - All valid suggestions,  I suppose, were the the code and the R process the question, but they are not (and so this is not intended to be a code review).  The R and LAStools output agree, and the question regards why they disagree with epsg.io and mygeodata.  Since my R and LAStools output agree with OSM and Google satellite I can uncomfortably disregard the difference at this point.  Just curious, really, but perhaps no one's come across this issue before. I've asked the folks at mygeodata directly and will post their reply, if they answer.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Your question seems interesting and well documented. We will try to anwser but it is currently not readable and some important information are missing so it is hard to grasp the problem. So, please edit and tidy your question following my comments.

Comment: From Anthony at mygeodata.cloud: "The Converter uses Proj.4 library to transform coordinates. When you are using EPSG codes, it may happen that different software has different definition of the projection. Try to use exact proj4 definition instead of EPSG code."    Not a useful answer, as I get the same results in R with OGCWKT, Proj.4, and the EPSG code.  I don't know what definition LAStools' las2las uses to get the same result as does R.  Has anyone experienced this disagreement in results with the same definition between your own and online platforms?

Comment: This is probably correct (at least partially). This is what I would like to check.

Comment: rgdal::rgdal_extSoftVersion() yields:
          GDAL "3.2.1", GDAL_with_GEOS  "TRUE",      PROJ  "7.2.1" ,    sp  "1.4-5".                                    
Also: sf_0.9-7     lidR_3.1.1   raster_3.4-5 sp_1.4-5, rgdal_1.5-23.

Comment: The OGSWKT def’n of EPSG:32613 includes, “PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],” – the closest I can come to an explanation to this mess is that one of the pairs of projection engines is not using this parameter.  Refining 0.9996 to 0.9996185 (in Excel Solver),  The epsg.io, etc., result 248974.68 * 0.9996185  +/- = R/LAStools result 248879.7. Despite the word ‘factor’ appearing in the parameter name, it could well be that this is a divisor that R/LAStools are not using.  Fiddling with the scale_factor value in the OGCWKT string in R has not gotten me to the epsg.io result, however.